# Shell Window within Textmate

Tags: shell, textmate

Is there a TextMate Plugin that provides a simple shell window within the editor window? I use the "Missing Drawer" plugin, which replaces the built-in project drawer, so i guess that it is basically possible to build such a thing. But is something like this out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess if you didn't find it via Google you won't find it here.

I've never seen such a plugin but there's a command to open a new Terminal.app window in the directory of the active file:

<kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

I think it's part of the shell scripting bundle.

Comment: I already use the 'Missing Drawer' which has a Button for opening the selected Folder in my favourite Terminal, but +1 for the Keystroke ;)

Comment: Correction: this keyboard shortcut `^`+`⇧`+`O` will open a directory which is active (i.e. selected) in the "**File Browser**". At least it is so in the latest (as of now) version of TextMate - **version 2.0.23**. So you can have one file opened in the editor and totally another directory **selected** in the "File Browser" panel. You can toggle the "File Browser" panel in the "View" menu or using the keyboard shortcut `^`+`⌥`+`⌘`+`D`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually writing something *for* the shell... which is presumably and presumptuously why you *want* the shell..  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will **RUN** your command/script!  Sorry if this is obvious.. but I use it all the time, and hadn't been aware of the fact until recently that this was possible..  It is also context aware, and semi-smartly "runs" whatever is "appropriate" for the type of "document" on which you are "working on".

**Edit:**  Since you want to stay "in" Textmate, but still have access to a real shell, I recommend [Visor](http://visor.binaryage.com/) or [dTerm](http://decimus.net/DTerm) - both of which will handle the job, with easy.  Personally, I like Visor.

[image]

Comment: I know that command, but thanks :). What i actually want is a shell window to make textmate kind of an 'IDE'. I often find myself switching between textmate and iterm, for things like rails development. Therefore, i thought that it would be very handy to have a built-in shell...